# Results of jQuery .serialize on textarea include odd characters

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form

```
<form name="theForm" id="theForm" action="index_hr_user.php" method="GET">
    <textarea name="udf_inset-alternateworkschedule" id="alternateworkschedule">Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</textarea>
</form>
```

There are more elements in the form

When I submit that form I do the following:

```
var details = $("#theForm").serialize();
```

`details` then is the following:

```
udf_inset-alternateworkschedule=Nulla+vitae+elit+libero%2C+a+pharetra+augue.¬e1=¬e2=
```

if I add in `alert($("#alternateworkschedule").serialize());`

I get: `udf_inset-alternateworkschedule=Nulla+vitae+elit+libero%2C+a+pharetra+augue.`

I have no idea where the **`¬e1=¬e2=`** is coming from when I serialize the form and it is causing problems in my subsequent insert/update query.

What am I missing?